# How will it show the selected value (SELECTED) in CodeIgniter 3.x?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to populate a drop-down list of the database. In my view file I have the following code

Here is my controller

```
$query = $this->interprete_model->interpreteID($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

print_r($query); 

$data['interprete'] = $query;
```

Aqui esta mi vista, usa set_select.

```
<select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">
 <option value="">- Select -</option>                                       
  <?php foreach($result as $row):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" 
    <?php echo set_select('regionI', $row->id, TRUE); ?>><?php echo $row->name;?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx9hz.jpg)

Many selected, I need one selected to modify (update) the data.

Comment: It's because you are passing `TRUE` value to every row in foreach loop. You should pass third argument as `TRUE` to `set_select()` function to just one row. Maybe you can make `if` statement like `if ($row->id == 'some_id') {/*logic without TRUE*/} else {/*other logic with TRUE*/}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this :**

```
<select class="form-control" name="regionI" id="regionI">
   <option value="">- Select -</option>                                       
   <?php foreach($users as $row):
     $selected = FALSE;
    // 1 is the id u want to be selected u can change it according to you
     if ($row->id == 1){
       $selected = TRUE;
    }
  ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" 
 <?php echo set_select('regionI', $row->id, $selected); ?>><?php echo $row->name;?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**You can also use `form_dropdown` as**

```
 // FOR ids
 $ids = array(1,2,3,4); // array of user ids
 echo form_dropdown('regionI',$ids,1,array('class'=>'form-control'));

// FOR name
 $names= array('name1','name2','name4','name3'); // array of user names
 echo form_dropdown('regionI',$names,'name1',array('class'=>'form-control'));
```

For More :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

i write this way for edit time selection

```
  <?php foreach ($select_single as $select_single_show):?>
     <select class="form-control" name="regionI">
              <?php foreach ($users as $row):?>
                  <option <?php if($row->id==$select_single_show->regionI)echo "selected";?> value="<?php echo $all_branch_show->id?>"><?php echo $row->name?>  
                  </option>
              <?php endforeach;?>
     </select>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```